# How to set environment variables via docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Is it not possible to specify the value of an environment variable for my docker-compose file when I perform the creation of a container?

My docker-compose file (creatively named `docker-compose.backend.yml`) has a section defining a variable:

```yaml
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ASPNETCOREENVIRONMENT}
```

And when I try to perform `docker-compose -f docker-compose.backend.yml -e ASPNETCOREENVIRONMENT=Development up -d`, it does not work and it replies with an error `unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e`. If I replace it with `--environment`, it replies with `unknown flag: --environment`.

Is there a reason why something like this is not supported? I use `Docker Compose version v2.24.3-desktop.1` on Windows, by the way.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/?

Comment: I am trying to avoid `.env` files.

Comment: off-topic on SO

Comment: Why off topic on SO? When `docker-compose` is a programming tool widely used

Comment: It's not really a programming tool _per se_.  On Meta Stack Overflow, see [Should Docker questions go on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-or-super-user) or [Question about running Docker got closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401112/question-about-running-docker-got-closed) for some more discussion.

Comment: I see your point and agree also the issue with docker is tool widely used by programmers as programming tool in this case developing c# app in the containers(or setup dev env). You also spitted it into 2 categories in [second link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401112/question-about-running-docker-got-closed) "more ops" and "more dev". Anyway I thanks for some more insights

Comment: @jonrsharpe the docs you linked to explicitly state "Values in your .env file can be overridden from the command line by using docker-compose up -e" (which appears to be incorrect…)

Comment: @davemyron true! That appears to be a typo, the [link target](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run---env) shows that working with `docker compose run`, **not** `up`. This is consistent with the CLI reference ([`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/#options), [`up`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/#options)).

Comment: [`docker/docs#18965`](https://github.com/docker/docs/issues/18965)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, you want to *"avoid `.env` files"*.

It's not directly supported by `up` sub command in Docker Compose, but you can do:

- On cmd (batch), Powershell

  ```
  set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  docker-compose up -d
  ```

  If you want to clean up after use

  ```
  set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=
  ```
- On Bash (Linux), Git Bash (Windows), etc. (it should work on any Unix shell)

  it's simpler (one line and it doesn't need cleaning)

  ```bash
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development docker-compose up -d
  ```

---

About last question

> Is there a reason why something like this is not supported?

There is already `.env` support that covers most of the uses cases to change environment without touching `compose` file

Also from [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run---env) you can use `-e` but only for `run` command

```bash
docker compose run -e ASPNETCOREENVIRONMENT=Development backend
```

Comment: `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development docker-compose up -d` can also be used on Windows if when `Git bash` is used. Thought I'd drop this here.

Comment: Yes, I changed answer a little as it's about more shell not system